# Writing HDFS data to external disk/tape

Tags: hadoop

I have 1TB of data on HDFS. Idont have that much space on my local disk to get that data to my local.

Is there any way that i can write the HDFS data directly to a external hard disk?

Answer (score 2):

If the disk is mapped on your machine, you should be able to do it using -get command

Answer (score 1):

The external drive that you attached is yet another local drive which is an extension to fixed hard drive(s). So, you could use copyToLocal option of the 'hadoop fs' command from the command line. 
Here is the link to for the details

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.18.3/hdfs_shell.html#copyToLocal

Additionally, Hadoop APIs can be used to copy a HDFS file to local drive. Refer the copyToLocalFile() method below.

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#copyToLocalFile